# How to take user input for less then 140 characters?

Tags: python

I am working on a python program. I want to take a user input which is less then 140 characters. If the sentence exceeds the word limit, It should just print the 140 characters. I am able to enter characters but this is what happens. I am new to python. How can I achieve this?

```
def isAlpha(c):
    if( c >= 'A' and c <='Z' or c >= 'a' and c <='z' or c >= '0' and c <='9'):
        return True
    else:
        return False


def main():
    userInput = str(input("Enter The Sentense: "))
    for i in range(140):
        newList = userInput[i]
        print(newList)
```

this is the output i get

```
Enter The Sentense: this is
t
h
i
s

i
s
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Manmohit/Desktop/anonymiser.py", line 11, in main
    newList = userInput[i]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
userInput = str(input("Enter The Sentense: "))
truncatedInput = userInput[:140]
```

Comment: It may help to mention that this is called Python's *slice* notation, and give some [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/the-python-slice-notation).

Comment: Also, `Sentense` should be `sentence` - no capital letter (it is not a "proper noun", and is not at the start of a sentence), and has a `c` after the `n`, not an `s`.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just test for the `len`?

```
if len(input) > 140:
   print "Input exceeds 140 characters."
   input = input[:140]
```

You can also put up other errors using this or quit the program, if you want to. The `input = input[:140]` makes sure that only the first 140 characters of the string are captured. This is wrapped around in an `if` so that if the input length is less than 140, the `input = input[:140]` line does not execute and the error is not shown.

This is called Python's Slice Notation, a useful link for quick learning would be [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/the-python-slice-notation)

Explanation for your error -

```
for i in range(140):
    newList = userInput[i]
    print(newList)
```

If the `userInput` is of length 5, then accessing the 6th element gives an error, since no such element exists. Similarly, you try to access elements until 140 and hence get this error. If all you're trying to do is split the string into it's characters, then, an easy way would be -

```
>>> testString = "Python"
>>> list(testString)
['P', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n']
```

Comment: But you don't even need to, because the slice notation silently allows for slices of more characters than there are available.

Comment: Yes. True. I just did this, so he would have a way to show an output message to the screen. :)

Answer (score 2):

`for i in range(140)` assumes there are 140 characters in the string. When you have finished iterating through the string, there won't be an index `n`, so an error is raised.

You can always iterate over a string:

```
for i in str(input("Enter a sentence: "))[:140]:
    print i
```

`[:140]` is [Python's Slice Notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/the-python-slice-notation?lq=1), which cuts the string from the first character to the 140th. Even if there is no 140th character, it just goes to the end of the string then.

Comment: +1 For explaining what the problem is, and suggesting a more elegant approach.